# PHP display all values of an array to use in mysql_fetch_array function?

Tags: php, arrays, mysql

I'm having a bit of difficulty using the values in a PHP array for a mysql function.

I have an array,

```
$a[0] = 89
$a[1] = 23
$a[2] = 15
$a[3] = 28
$a[4] = ...
```

And I need to generate a string like so:

```
$result_array = 'ID = 89 OR ID = 23 OR ID = 15 OR ID = 28 OR ID = ...';
```

To fetch values from my DB:

```
$result_test = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Events Where $result_array");
```

But I do not know how to create the string $result_array from the array $a.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$result_test = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Events Where ID in (".implode(',' , $a).")");
```

Use the IN operator and send the list as `89,23,15,28` etc

So the query will become `ID in (89,23,15,28)`

Comment: geez! 14 secs!! arg! you wrote `$a` instead of `$result_array` I should give you a big -1 :P

Comment: pick this because it was waay faster (14 sec)

Comment: how I can't give you another +1 there

Comment: @yes123: No, because the source array is `$a`. `$result_array` is the name of the intermediate string in the OP's hypothetical solution, which did not get used in this answer.

Comment: @Tomalak we sorted it out, yes123 and I were just having a little fun :)

Comment: @Sabeen: Fun is off-topic on SO.

Comment: @Tomalak .. i think fun is never off-topic, especially when it comes to being part of a (free) community but i will definitely keep that in mind :)

Comment: @Sabeen: Well it's a Q&A community, not a message board, and cost has nothing to do with anything. Sorry :)

Comment: @Tomalak okie dokie boss .. fun is off-topic from now on .. i promise!

Answer (score 1):

```
$result_test = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Events Where ID IN (".implode(',',$a).')');
```

Comment: actually $result_array is the string he is trying to form, so i used the $a array directly :)

Comment: oh my. Very late here need to sleep. +1 to your answer and comment